# Get the id of the selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've 2 dialog forms `Add region` and `Add country`. There are `<select>` options in each modal form. There can be select options which are repeated in each modal form, so I'm putting those in a class and styling it by `display:none`, so the id's does not get repeated.

When I need to get the id of the item selected, it gives me an undefined value. I'm using `$(".region_options").children(":selected").attr("id");` to get the id of the selected option.

Here is my code. and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGpZH/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <script>
  $(function() {

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {
          var region_id =  $(".region_options").children(":selected").attr("id");
          alert(region_id)
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },

    });

    $( "#create-user" ).button().click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  });


  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
    <select class="region_options">
        <option>Select Region</option>
        <option id="1">Asia / Pacific</option>
        <option id="2">North America</option>
        <option id="3">sdgvgwqrg</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="dialog-form1" title="Create new user" style="display:none">
   <select class="region_options">
        <option>Select Region</option>
        <option id="1">Asia / Pacific</option>
        <option id="2">North America</option>
        <option id="3">sdgvgwqrg</option>
    </select>
</div>


<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<option>` elements are identified by the `value` attribute, not `id`.

```
<select class="region_options">
    <option>Select Region</option>
    <option value="1">Asia / Pacific</option>
    <option value="2">North America</option>
    <option value="3">sdgvgwqrg</option>
</select>
```

Use `val()` method to read or write the value of the selected option.

```
var region = $("#dialog-form .region_options").val();
$("#dialog-form1 .region_options").val(region);
```

Comment: Great answer but notice that `$(".region_options")` matches multiple elements.

Comment: It gives me `Select Region`, I rather want 1,2,3 as per the item selected.

Comment: You need to update the jquery selector to match the correct select. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line you are using from:

```
$(".region_options").children(":selected").attr("id");
```

to:

```
$(".region_options").children(":selected").parent().parent().attr("id")
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UGpZH/9/)

Answer (score 0):

It will work with the id I have have worked on your js fiddle the javascript code

```
`$(function() {

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {
          var region_id =  $("#select_region").val();
          alert(region_id);
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },

    });

    $( "#create-user" ).button().click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  });`
```

and the html code will be :

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
    <select id="select_region" class="region_options">
        <option>Select Region</option>
        <option value="1">Asia / Pacific</option>
        <option value="2">North America</option>
        <option value="3">sdgvgwqrg</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="dialog-form1" title="Create new user" style="display:none">
   <select class="region_options">
        <option>Select Region</option>
        <option value="1">Asia / Pacific</option>
        <option value="2">North America</option>
        <option value="3">sdgvgwqrg</option>
    </select>
</div>


<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
```

use id as an attribute in spite of using class `<select id="select_region" class="region_options">`

Answer (score 0):

As `this` refers to the modal (your `#dialog-form` element) we are able to select the `select` element within it rather than all of them.

```
$(function() {

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {

          var region_id = $(this).find(".region_options").val(); // Solution

          if (!region_id)
            alert('Please select a region.');
          else
            alert('Selected region: ' + region_id);
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });

    $( "#create-user" ).button().click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
      });

  });
```

See [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change your markup or use the `.val` function. You are able to get the ids like that:

```
$(function() {

  $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Create an account": function() {
          var region_id = $(this).find(".region_options option:selected").attr("id");
          alert(region_id);
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    },

  });

  $( "#create-user" ).button().click(function() {
      $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

Here is your jsfiddle updated:

http://jsfiddle.net/UGpZH/13/

The problem is that you are selecting the wrong drop-down.